# Enabling "--shell-escape" on TeXworks under MiKTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot, texworks, shell-escape

After resolving the problem on [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126410/how-to-project-a-function-over-a-3d-plane), I applied to finally install [Gnuplot 4.6](http://www.gnuplot.info/); *and after a successful installation* I had to allow the `--shell-escape` option on TeXworks, so I added a new Typesetting Tool on the Preferences menu, called `pdfLaTeX+ShellEscape`.

The lines of code inserted into the tool configuration are listed below:

```
$synctexoption
-undump=pdflatex
--shell-escape
$fullname
```

The problem is that when I try to compile my MWE (MYname.tex) with the above specified option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{axis}[no markers,samples=30]
\addplot gnuplot{atanh(x)};
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

I get this messge:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'MYname.pgf-plot.table'
could not be found. Maybe you need to enable the shell-escape feature? For 
pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also invoke 
'>> gnuplot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file..

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.7     \addplot gnuplot{atanh(x)};
?
```

I am running TeXworks 0.44, and until now it didn't show this kind of stubbornness because I compiled every document without problems.

I did also some research and I found that I could write `-enable-write18` but *even after this try I get the same errmsg* and so I'm stuck again with the plots problem (although I discovered a powerful program like Gnuplot I don't know how to set LaTeX properly).

P.S. : Sorry for the deleted question with the same title, that issue was created by a simple human error.

Comment: Check the folder to see if there is a `.gnu` file with the name of the `.tex` file.  It may be even a `.dot` something else but it wont be `aux`, `log`, and the standard `LaTeX` ones.

Comment: I found the file `MYname.pgf-plot.gnuplot` on the same folder, in addition to the classic `aux` and `log` files, but at this point I don't know what to do.

Comment: What happened was `gnu` didn't process the file.  If you process this file now, you will have the `.table` or it may name it a `.tex` file and then all will work.  This happens sometimes with shell escape enabled.  It has to do with something you havent set in `TeXworks` I presume.

Comment: I'm sure it will look like that I don't deserve my rep. points, but I have to aks this question: by processing this single file do I have to open it with gnuplot program? If so I already tried this but I got the same error.

Comment: What I've done is: go to the file `MYname.pgf-plot.gnuplot`, r-click and select wgnuplot program to open the specific extension, after that the `MYname.pgf-plot.table` was created and *it all worked like a charm*. Now the only question is if I've set the Typesetting tool correctly, because I don't know if I've done some mistake

Comment: Ahh... Now I see some light, because after the creation of `MYname.pgf-plot.table` I re-compiled my file with the only option `-shell-escape` and *it finally worked*. Thanks to the answers dustin.

Comment: @ texenthusiast I run under Windows 7 Home Professional, and MiKTeX 2.9.4813

Comment: Use [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/15717) like  [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) or [arara](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) with `shell-escape` to automate the compiling and run enough number of times to get the plot.

Comment: At this point I have already solved my issue but thanks to the advice, I'll keep that in mind in case of another problem like this.

Comment: @ dustin I have tried and it worked well, I got the same result as the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, I tested, and the problem had disappeared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since we were able to establish that the compilation generated a `.pgf-plot.gnuplot` file, the problem was that this file was not compiled in `gnuplot`.

We now have a few options:

1. run `gnuplot` on the `.pgf-plot.gnuplot` file to create a `.table` or `.tex` file and then compile again.
2. we can modify the calling of `--shell-escape` for TeXworks to `--tex-option=--shell-escape` and then compile again without running `gnuplot` this time.
3. another option posed by `texenthusiast` is to use a program such as `Latexmk` to compile multiple times; however, I still believe we would need options two's modification of `--shell-escape` which was discussed on `TUG`'s message board here https://www.tug.org/pipermail/texworks/2011q2/004166.html

Comment: Also Make sure the system wide path for `gnuplot` is set properly depending on Linux or Windows

Comment: @texenthusiast you can edit the post and add that were you feel it is most appropriate before the list, in the list, or part of a list item.