# Stack figures in horizontal plane in 3D rectangular shape without loss of quality

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, stack

I am plotting figures on GMT but it does not support some features in gridview.
So I want stack each figure on different platforms below each other.
E.g. I want to add each image like the following

[image: Stack of figures]

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please provide a fully compilable (minimum working) example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) of your efforts and data file(s) or links to them? The solvers usually cannot work from a scratch on such a big task.

Comment: Refers GMT to "The Generic Mapping Tools"? You have to provide more information.

Comment: Its tomography maps, I plot data on GMT (Generic Mapping Tools). I want to add some features like in link below and stack it but GMT not supported vector in grid view so I plot each separate and stack on different platform https://www.dropbox.com/s/dc7282i7i3lmted/Isotropy.pdf

Comment: Some time ago I asked a [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154780). But for the colorbar you need a different approach.

Answer (score 9):

I'll show you how to stack external files on top of one another in the manner you want, assuming you've got the ticks, axes labels and titles of the main square images in the external files. I used the file you linked in your comment for the bottom layer, and since there were no other ones (and the higher ones are different - no axes labels), I used some random images. My approach was to adjust [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114558/19372) of a similar question. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Layers
\begin{scope}[x={(-0.7cm,0.4cm)}, y={(.9cm,.2cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=0,transform shape] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{isotropy3.pdf}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=2,transform shape] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{kitten1.jpg}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=4,transform shape] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{kitten2.jpg}};
\node[canvas is yx plane at z=6,transform shape] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{kitten3.jpg}};
\end{scope}
% Legend
\node[draw,inner sep=.3pt,line width=2pt,anchor=south west] at (4.7,-1.2) {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=.2cm]{gradient.jpg}};
\foreach \x\y in {0/-4,.24/-3,.48/-2,.72/-1,.96/0}{
  \draw[line width=1pt] (4.75+\x*3,-.92)--+(270:.45);
  \node[anchor=north] at (4.75+\x*3,-1.35) {$\mathsf\y$};
}
\node at (6.3,-2.2) {\sf dc/cprem (\%)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can fiddle around with the arguments for the `scope` environment to change the projection of the images. I also included a little drawing of one of your legends using `TikZ`, in case you wanted to do that, using an external image ([this one](http://www.paintshopprotutorials.co.uk/assets/images/square_rainbow_gradient_gif_non_trans.gif)) for the gradient. Here is the result:

[image]

The bottom file is called `isotropy.pdf`, the one above it is `kitten1.jpg`, then `kitten2.jpg`, and finally `kitten3,jpg` on top, all of which are located in the same directory as your main `.tex` file.

Comment: Thank you so much @JanisL, One error "File `standalone.cls' not found. ^^M"(I used \documentclass{article} it works) and quality of output is loss, quality is so important for me.

Comment: You can get the `standalone` package [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) if your distribution doesn't have it. I'm assuming that you mean that the output has less quality, but I'm not sure what that exactly means. There is no compression of images done in the compiling, and if you want a larger image, simply change `[width=5cm]` to `[width=10cm]` or something larger.

Comment: @Satish Assuming you're using a standard distribution, you can use the package manager to install `standalone` and this is recommended. (Much less likely to cause issues than installing a downloaded copy manually.) But, as you discovered, you don't actually need it here.