# Convert an svg to an eps file that meets the requirements of the pst-solides3d package

Tags: eps, pst-solides3d

I want to use an eps file in a pst-solides3d environment, e.g. like in the code below

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d} 
\begin{document}
\psset{Decran=20}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psset{solidmemory}
\psSolid[object=cube, name=OBJECT]%
\psImage[file=tiger.eps,normal=OBJECT 4 solidnormaleface, origine=OBJECT 4 solidcentreface]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The documentation says on page 168 that "*the eps image must be prepared according to the method described in the documentation for ‘pst-anamorphosis’* ". Although my French is quite good, I could not find anything about it in that document. Furthermore, I have read in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166313/82926) answer that the eps image has to have "*only basic line elements, like lineto curveto and moveto*".

Can anyone tell me how to create such an eps from an existing SVG file? I would prefer to work directly with Inkscape or another freely available program.

For testing I created a simple rectangle in Inkscape and saved it as an eps-file. When compiling I don't get any error or warning. It just produces a blank page. When I use the "tiger.eps" from the author's homepage, it works just fine and produces the desired result.

Comment: does the svg you have fail if so what error do you get? an eps could for example just be a thin wrapper around an image bitmap not really scalable at all, that would be a problem for pstricks to interpret, but you wouldn't expect such a thing from svg.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually I don't get any error or warning. It just produces a blank page. When I use the "tiger.eps" that they provide at their homepage, it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "flattened" EPS file, which can be generated using the `pstoedit` tool.

```
pstoedit -f psf rectangle.eps rectangle-flat.eps
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helped. I figured out, that the eps file can also be created with -f ps flag, so that curves are also allowed. Furthermore the -rgb flag is helpful. In my opinion the tool "pstoedit" should definitively be mentioned in the documentation of pst-solides3d!